# Bad symbolic reference in SBT scala project

Tags: scala, refactoring, sbt

I did a small refactoring, everything is still syntactically correct and it should compile for sure. However, I got an error:

```
[error] bad symbolic reference. A signature in MyClass123.class refers to type MyClass456
[error] in package com.mypackage which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling MyClass123.class.
[error] one error found
```

I **didn't change** anything else. I even revert code to the previous, unrefactored version but the error remains. I tried to reload sbt also.

Maybe I need to clean the project from sbt generated files somehow? If not, what do I do?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980269/build-error-for-scala-slick-2-0-0, rather the solution to that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you need, indeed, clean the project. Just type `sbt clean`.